# How i Do SVG Background Url with online file

Tags: html, svg

Hello every one i have question about that how i do online url of svg file i have used the below code it worked for offline but not working with internet file ... check the below code .

```
.selected::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("D://arrow-down.svg");

  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;

  transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

this above code is worked but when i change the background url to like the below code then not working

```
background: url("https://hazratalitokhi.weebly.com/uploads/4/5/3/1/45316171/arrow-down.svg");
```

Comment: https://hazratalitokhi.weebly.com/uploads/4/5/3/1/45316171/arrow-down.svg does not have a mime-type of image/svg+xml

Answer (score 0):

As was commented, SVG needs to be enabled on the server.  If you have a file called .htaccess, you can add the following to it:

```
#Allow SVG files
#-------------------------------
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
```

That needs to be done to enable SVG on a server.